# How to do Eager loading and Explicit loading in MassTransit Saga Persistence for Object Graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, masstransit, saga

Automatonymous in MassTransit is one of the best State Machine implementations in .Net and we decided to use it in our internal systems ;however, we are having problem configuring the Saga for loading and updating Saga instance in Entity Framework.

We don't have any control over loading data in EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<>. For example if it is required to update part of the instance or do the explicit loading, there will be no options for that.
Although you can have full control of mapping your Saga to SQL (By IEntityTypeConfiguration<>), this will not give you any option to define which part of object graph should be loaded for particular state. Unless i'm missing something here.

You can easily replicate this issue with making a Saga with one to one relationship. if you publish to Saga to update the details of a main entity, you will get Primary key duplication SQL error because only the main entity as Saga been loaded to DbContext and you try to update the details which will be null.

I tried to attach the detail entity to DbContext by Activity<> before get into the Saga state but when it saved the changes the details entity state was Added not Modified

Comment: You need to make your mappings properly. This has nothing to do with MassTransit. If you can put your code to Github, may be people can help.